# Multiple section for an article marked with schema.org/Article

Tags: html, schema.org

Suppose to have an article in an HTML Web page. The aim is to markup the content using such a schema (I prefer those provided by [schema.org](http://schema.org)). Hence, one starts to markup the contents by following the [schema.org/Article](http://schema.org/Article). The point is, if the article belongs to multiple sections, should one put each section in a separate span as follows:

```
<span itemprop="articleSection">Section1</span> -
<span itemprop="articleSection">Section2</span> -
<span itemprop="articleSection">Section3</span>
```

or it is equivalent to let them in a unique span like in the following?

```
<span itemprop="articleSection">Section1 - Section2 - Section3</span>
```

Comment: Looking at other examples (see for instance the itemprop "breadcrumb" of a [WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) or an [Offer](http://schema.org/Offer)), seems that the second schema is appropriate. Notwithstanding that, I see that for a breadcrumb, the anchors, <a>, certainly identify the address of the breadcrumb. How the different sections can be identified in the second example? Doh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your article is part of many different sections, then you should mark each one as a articleSection like in your first example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <span itemprop="name">President to throw ceremonial first pitch at Nationals Park</span>
  by <span itemprop="author">John Smith</span>
  <span itemprop="articleSection">Sports</span> -
  <span itemprop="articleSection">Politics</span> -
  <span itemprop="articleSection">US News</span>
</div>
```